# Resize collectionviewcell after downloading the image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have a horizontal collectionview(1 row) with images. At first they are all the same size, but when I finish downloading them I want to resize them. I have everything working, I can resize the image, put it in the cell, I just need to resize the cell after downloading it. I checked some answers here but they did not solve my problem. Here is my code

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! myCell

    let key = photosList[indexPath.row]

    storageRefToObserve.child(key).downloadURL { url in
            cell.profileImage.sd_setImage(with: url) // deleted completion block for now
    }
    return cell
}
```

I also had a completion block but I deleted it for now, becuse it didnt help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to set cell size according to image size ?

Comment: Yes. I have a function that takes the image and returns me a resized image with static height 125 and new width keeping the aspect ratio. I then want to change the cell size according to the image I have.

Comment: you need to go with custom FlowLayout else need the size of image from the backend and make it according to aspect ratio of your cell